# Check if a character is a space

Tags: c

I'm creating an absurdly simple program in C to mess around with `getchar()`. The program will print out what you input until you press enter and it will guarantee that your lines are no more than 80 chars each. To do this, I keep a running count of how many characters have been entered. Once the char count hits 70, the next space encountered will cause a line break. If no space is encountered between 70-80, a line break will occur regardless. I realize this is a super naive implementation and could be optimized left and right, but remember, I'm just messing around:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (lineLengthCount < 70) {
        putchar(c);
        lineLengthCount++;
    }   
    else if (lineLengthCount < 80 && (c == ' ')) {
        printf("%c\n", c); 
        lineLengthCount = 0;
    }   
    else {
        printf("%c\n", c); 
        lineLengthCount = 0;
    }   
}
```

The problem is the `c == ' '` conditional doesn't seem to be actually checking for a space. I get output like this:

```
fitter happier more productive comfortable not drinking too much regula
r exercise at the gym three days a week getting on better with your ass
ociate employee contemporaries at ease eating well no microwaved dinner
```

where I was hoping that the lines would be truncated when a space was encountered. Instead, no matter what character is entered after line 70, a new line is created. am I missing something?  Does `' '` really mean any character?

Comment: Both last blocks seem to be doing the same thing.

Comment: Even if the condition in your else-if is false, your else will execute and put a line break.

Comment: And if `LineLengthCount` is `70` ... ? you reset it to `0`.

Comment: The code in the `if` part and the code in the `else` part are absolutely equal. How do you differentiate between them?

Comment: @user1427661 Actually, it's not considering any nonspace characters between 70 and 80 would not get printed at all. Does my second example in my answer work? I haven't tested it, but it is much shorter. I think it's structure better matches what you're actually doing, also.

Comment: Yes. you're right, that is much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (lineLengthCount < 70) {
        putchar(c);
        lineLengthCount++;
    }   
    else if (lineLengthCount < 80 && (c == ' ')) {
        printf("%c\n", c); 
        lineLengthCount = 0;
    }   
    else if (lineLengthCount >= 80){
        printf("%c\n", c); 
        lineLengthCount = 0;
    }
    else{
        putchar(c);
        lineLengthCount++;
    }
}
```

I think this should work. That should prevent the else from executing when there are less than 80 characters but the character isn't a space.

EDIT: I realized now that instead if lineLengthCount is less than 80 but the character isn't a space it wouldn't get printed at all, so I added another else at the end to fix it.

Wouldn't this be shorter and more concise?

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    putchar(c);
    if((c == ' ' && lineLengthCount >= 70) || lineLengthCount >= 80){
        printf("\n");
        lineLengthCount = 0;
    }
    else
        ++lineLengthCount;
}
```

Comment: Non-space characters between 70th and 80th position will be lost!

Comment: @MártonMolnár I realized that just as you said it. xD Does that work?

Answer (score 4):

There's a problem with your conditions: if `lineLengthCount` is > 70 but the next character is not a space, the last `else` will be hit, breaking line and resetting the counter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're at all unsure of what's going on, I would recommend breaking up the "if" conditional into three explicit checks:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    lineLengthCount++;
    if (lineLengthCount < 70) {
        putchar(c);
    }   

    if (lineLengthCount < 80 && (c == ' ')) {
        printf("%c\n", c); 
        lineLengthCount = 0;
    }   

    if (lineLengthCount == 80) {
        printf("%c\n", c); 
        lineLengthCount = 0;
    }   
}
```

If you want to see what's happening, write some debugging output in each "if" to notice when it is called.

Once it works, and you understand why, you can edit it down and combine the "ifs" ...

Answer (score 1):

Using ' ' is completely valid. You could also try using the C standard library function isspace() to check if the character is a space. This function returns a boolean expression, As in:

```
char ch = '0';

if (isspace(ch))
    //the char is a space...
```

By 'is space' this function actually means is any 'whitespace' character, so that includes '\n' or any other character that prints as empty space.

You could also the decimal value 32 which means the same as a space:

```
if (ch==32)
```

However for readability I would rather use the first version!