# Detect white space in the input

Tags: c, input, fgets, fgetc

I want to make a program that only accepts lowercase characters from the user.
And I want it to print an error whenever there is a whitespace, a capital letter in the input or any character beside the alphabet.

But my code is behaving in an unexpected manner, I'm not sure why.
The error message is printed only if a whitespace or a capital letter was the first character that was entered in the input. How is it possible even though I am scanning the whole string with `fgetc` looking for a whitespace?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ( void )
{
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    char ch = fgetc(stdin);
    if  (fgets( buff, sizeof buff, stdin ) != NULL && islower(ch)) {
        while (ch != ' ' && ch != EOF)
        {
            printf("There are No Spaces in the input!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Error\n");
}
```

Comment: [to check for whitespace use `isspace`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15326729/995714), and [`fgets` returns `int`, not `char`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8464030/995714), because EOF and the character code 0xFF are different

Comment: "I want to make a program that only accepts lowercase characters from the user." and "print an error whenever there is a whitespace ..."  -->> So you want to "accept" both lower case and white-space, etc., just do different things with them?

Comment: @chux I don't want to accept white space, I want to detect them and print error when they are in input

Comment: After white-space is detected and an error is printed, it that it? Just quit the program?

Comment: @chux I solved that issue , but now i have another problem.
I want to print the error message if there is less than two messages in the input and if the input is only " | ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not scanning the whole string. You're getting the first character into ch, then you're getting the rest of the line into buff (more or less), and then if ch was a lower-case character, your program will print "There are no spaces" over and over because you never again change ch.

Comment: A couple other notes: fgetc returns an int, not a char. And islower can misbehave when passed char if the char is signed (as on some computer architectures) and the char has the most significant bit 0x80 set.

Comment: How do i scan the whole string? using : while (fgetc(stdin) != ' ' || fgetc(stdin) != EOF) ? Also is there an alternative to islower?

Comment: You'll want to save the character returned from fgetc so you can compare it a few times. Like: while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch == ' ')...
islower is fine, just make sure you declare ch as int instead of char. islower is valid for all values returned from fgetc.