# How to print out the last letters of the words in C

Tags: c, string

Got stucked at this point of the task. There is a 60 characters block (char) and my task would be that I have to print out the last letters of the words in the block. My suggest would be that before the (spaces) ' ' staying letter should be printed out. I mean a function check all letters and when there is a space it should count back one character and print it out.
Since now I could not really find the right function for checking down all characters. Isalpha function could help me?

Comment: You can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326729/check-if-a-character-is-a-space

Comment: What do you mean by "last letters"? Like the last word after the last space in the string? Can you show an example of the "block" you have, and tell us what part of it you need to print? And please try to create a [mcve] of your attempt. Lastly please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: For example : there is a 60 characters block which contains words. I have to print out these word's last letter. "hey this computer looks cool". Y S R S L

Comment: As I am home I will copy my attempt

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a string (or an array in general) from the first character to the last? Do you know how to recognize specific characters like space (`' '`) or [categories of characters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification)? Then you have the basics of what you need, you just need to figure out how to get the previous character when you find a space.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 char s[61]={0};
 fgets(s,60,stdin);
 printf("s=%s", s);
 int i;
 int szo;
 for (i = 0; s[i] ; i++)
 {
  if(szo)
  { 
   if(!isalpha(s[i]))
    szo=0;
    } 
 }
    return 0;
}

Comment: thats my attempt

Answer (score -1):

Here you are. I suppose that the string contains only letters and blanks. That is the word is a sequence of characters limited by blanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "How to print out the last letters of the words in C";
    const char * blanks = " \t";

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; )
    {
        size_t j = strspn( s + i, blanks );
        i += j;

        j = strcspn( s + i, blanks );

        i += j;

        if ( j != 0 ) printf( "%c ", s[i-1] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
w o t t e t s f e s n C
```

If you need to output letters in the upper case then include the header `<ctype.h>` and change the output statement like

```
if ( j != 0 ) printf( "%c ", toupper( ( unsigned char )s[i-1] ) );
```